# The react-native init hangs on macOS Catalina, with fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule react-native@0.64.2 checking installable status

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, npx

I just wanted to create a **react native** application using `react-native init` command. But it hangs with the message:

> fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule react-native@0.64.2 checking
> installable status

Sure I am not the first one facing the same issue and I found many answers and tried almost all solutions I found while googling it,

Examples are:

1. Uninstall and reinstall `node`
2. Install `yarn`
3. Clear `npm` cache
4. Install `node` using `home-brew` instead of direct installation
5. `npm i -g react-native`; then `react-native init`

and many other solutions, but it is still stuck.

It is not related to the MacOS version or Network connectivity etc anyway; because It worked on another machine with same OS, and on the same network.

I am sure the react native community is familiar with the question and may somebody will say this is **already answered** and thus will close it, **but it still hangs**. I don't know what the issue is.

I am not sure it is related to `node` or `npm` or some other. Because I faced the same issue, when I tried `create-react-app`.

I just wanted to know is there any solution to solve the issue?

and

is there anyway the `node`, `npm` or `npx` or other produce some error when it hangs for any reason, may be while downloading some dependency or while running some commands etc; and show some information regarding what is happened and what is missing.

Assuming this is more related to `node`, `npm` or `npx`; as these are responsible for downloading and running the modules and dependencies or it can be because of error handling in `react-native init`. Whichever, may be assuming everything fine on the machine, and may not be checking and reporting, if something is missing.

[Screenshot: React Js and React-Native hangs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3RPT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Few days after, surprisingly, it started working. I didn't change anything and I was planned to try a fresh installation of everything from OS installation. But now, I got it working, with no notable reason.